# linear model, given y, calculate the confidence interval for x

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, inverse-prediction

I fit the model `y = a + b * x`. And 95% CI for estimates of a and b are (a1, a2), (b1, b2), respectively.

If we have a new observation `x0`, then the estimated response is `a_hat + b_hat * x0`. And the 95% CI is `(a1 + b1 * x0, a2 + b2 * x0)`

Case 1, now given `y = 0`, I want to estimate the responding `x`. 
I guess the confidence interval for `x` is `(a1 / b2, a2 / b1)`. Am I right?

Case 2, if we fit a model `y = a + b * x + c * z + d * x * z` , `a_hat<0, b_hat,c_hat,d_hat>0`,
Given y = 0, how to calculate the confidence interval for `x + z`?

Comment: For these questions to be answerable you need to supply more information, including (at a minimum) the *probabilistic* terms in each model and the method by which the parameters are being estimated.

Comment: For OLS regression, it is not the case that the 95% CI for $\hat y$ is $(a_l + b_lx_0,\ a_u + b_ux_0)$.

Comment: Yea. We still need error term. I think this problem is looking for a calibration interval.

Comment: What is a "calibration interval" in this context?

Comment: The 95% confidence interval for the estimated X will be given by the points where the `y=Y`horizontal line intersects the lower and upper confidence bands of the regression line

Comment: @whuber: in this context, calibration is inverse prediction. See p145 of Seber&Lee Linear Regression Analysis (2ed)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking about *inverse prediction*, also known as *calibration*. In short, if you have a linear regression model
$$
  Y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x +\epsilon
$$
and you estimate it based on some selected values $x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n$. Then, you want to use the estimated model (and estimated parameters $\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta_1}$ to find the value of $x$ that will give some choosen value of $Y$, say $y_0$, and a confidence interval for that $x$.

This is discussed in [Seber and Lee, page 145](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471415405), for instance, with many references. There is a dedicated R package on CRAN ,`investr`. And it has been discussed on this site [Error bars, linear regression and "standard deviation" for point](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206531/error-bars-linear-regression-and-standard-deviation-for-point)

(I will try to come back to post a fuller account)